# how to use one method for all clickable items using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What would be the best way to make the following jquery script into a single method which can be resued with all of my clickable spans? As you can see each click event is doing almost the exact same thing except for the specific CSS class and the spans unique ID. I have thought about using the jquery .children() method but I'm not sure how to assign the specific class to each span. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<p class="clickHolder">
    <span id="click1">Select Step 1</span> 
    <span id="click2">Select Step 2</span> 
    <span id="click3">Select Step 3</span> 
    <span id="click4">Select Step 4</span> 
    <span id="click5">Select Step 5</span>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#click1").click(function () {
            $("#wizardSteps").removeClass();
            $("#wizardSteps").addClass("step1");
        });

        $("#click2").click(function () {
            $("#wizardSteps").removeClass();
            $("#wizardSteps").addClass("step2");
        });

        $("#click3").click(function () {
            $("#wizardSteps").removeClass();
            $("#wizardSteps").addClass("step3");
        });

        $("#click4").click(function () {
            $("#wizardSteps").removeClass();
            $("#wizardSteps").addClass("step4");
        });

        $("#click5").click(function () {
            $("#wizardSteps").removeClass();
            $("#wizardSteps").addClass("step5");
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('[id^="click"]').click(function () {
    var stepnum = $(this).attr('id').substr(5);
    $("#wizardSteps").removeClass();
    $("#wizardSteps").addClass("step" + stepnum);
});
```

Comment: I love it I use it all the time ;)

Comment: @RJD well.... From this day on I'll use it too! :) and great combination with the standard JS method `substr()` !! Nice indeed

Comment: That's an outstanding little script you have there. One question just so that I understand what's going on here, when you're doing '^' does that mean all items of that ID will be selected?

Comment: It selects all the elements that start with click: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<p class="clickHolder">
    <span class="clickable" id="click1">Select Step 1</span> 
    <span class="clickable" id="click2">Select Step 2</span> 
    <span class="clickable" id="click3">Select Step 3</span> 
    <span class="clickable" id="click4">Select Step 4</span> 
    <span class="clickable" id="click5">Select Step 5</span>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".clickable").click(function () {
            $("#wizardSteps").removeClass();
            $("#wizardSteps").addClass( /* calculate step */);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This was my first thought to, but you are not adding the class `step1` to each item. The class is different each time. You must parse the appropriate number from the id in order to know which class to add.

Comment: +1 I prefer this one (browser performance for one reason) if you need to substring the id to get some value you wanna work with your markup could be improved maybe check http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Comment: Thanks guys. You're right. I was too lazy to think about how to calculate that ID, as that was not the main issue anyway...